# copying list of semicolon delimited files from txt file to given folder in windows cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-scripting

i have text file that contains eg:

```
c:\test\test1.txt;d:\test2\j.js;d:test2\2.cs
```

I need to copy those files that are delimited using windows command line bat file to given folder that is passed to bat file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy, actually:

```
for /f %%l in (somefile.txt) do (
    for %%f in (%%l) do (
        copy "%%f" %1
    )
)
```

The first loop iterates line-wise over the file; the second one will split at semicolons (and other things, e.g. spaces and commas). If the file names look like those you provided it should work.

If the copy destination(s) looks like that too, just add two more loops, obviously:

```
for /f %%l in (somefile.txt) do (
    for %%f in (%%l) do (
        for /f %%k in (destination.txt) do (
            for %%g in (%%k) do (
                copy "%%f" %%g
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: what if i need to copy destination will be like this

Comment: @Joey when i run ---------------for /f %%l in (d:\BuildServer\BuildScripts\sourceFilelist.csv) do ( for %%f in (%%l) do ( for %%k in (d:\BuildServer\BuildScripts\Destinationlist.csv) do ( for %%g in (%%k) do ( copy "%%f" %%g ) ) ) ) ------------- Destinationlist.csv file replaced with source file list and finaly its content replaced with last file of the source file list and the cmd out put prints %g and %k as characters it self, ie not with values assigned to them didnt work as i expected

Comment: @DSharper, ask another question, please.

Comment: Just change `for %%k` to `for /f %%k`

Comment: Ah, thanks, mousio. I have to admit not to have tried understanding what the code vomit wanted to say me in DSharper's comment, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files from file list with the following batch-file command:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=;" %%f in (filelist.txt) do copy %%f %1
```

Assuming filelist.txt has each file name on a separate line:

```
c:\test\test1.txt;
d:\test2\j.js;
d:\test2\2.cs
```

No idea how to parse single line though.